# Can I Sync a Sharepoint 2013 Image (or Asset) Library with OneDrive for Business?

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

At some point this could not be done.

Has this been fixed?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in SharePoint 2013 online and on-premise, we still cannot sync image or asset library with OneDrive for business in SharePoint online and on-premise.

You can submit feedbacks at [UserVoice](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/86090-onedrive-for-business).

There is a similar post:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-cant-i-sync-a-sharepoint-image-library-to-my/38b07327-db1b-4fe0-bb34-498b41898951